# Estimator.predict in a loop cause memory leak in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks

When I use tensorflow `estimator.predict`, this happened to me.
Say, I have an estimator load from the saved model by this:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, config=run_cfg)
```

a `get_input_fn()` that will return `input_fn` like this:

```
def get_input_fn(arg1, arg2):
    def input_fn():
        # do something
        #    ....
        return features, None
    return input_fn
```

Then, a loop will be used to predict all the input from a `file_iter` like this:

```
for idx, data in enumerate(file_iter):
    predicts = estimator.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn(data['query'],
                                                    data['responses']))
```

This will case memory leak. After each call of `estimator.predict`, the memory will increase a little bit, but never down. I use `objgraph` to debug my code, and find some reference count increase after each call of `estimator.predict`.

I don't really know the insight of `estimator.predict`. And i guess the problem may because i call input_fn more than once. The version of my tensorflow is v1.2.

---

### [UPDATE]

Here are the result of `objgraph`, left is before calling `estimator.predict`, mid is after calling it, right is another call result. As i see, the `tuple`, `list`, `dic` increase a bit after each call of `estimator.predict`. I didn't draw the reference graph because i am not familiar with it.

```
objgraph.show_most_common_types()    
tuple            146247 | tuple            180157   | tuple            213976
list             60745  | list             73107    | list             86111
dict             43412  | dict             50925    | dict             58437
function         28482  | function         28497    | function         28512
TensorShapeProto 9434   | TensorShapeProto 11793    | TensorShapeProto 14152
Dimension        8286   | Dimension        10360    | Dimension        12434
Operation        6098   | Operation        7625     | Operation        9152
AttrValue        6098   | NodeDef          7625     | NodeDef          9152
NodeDef          6098   | TensorShape      7575     | TensorShape      9092
TensorShape      6058   | Tensor           7575     | Tensor           9092
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i found this is caused by call too many `tf.convert_to_tensor` , each time calling that function will generate a new node in tensorflow graph, which needs some memory.

To solve this problem, just use `tf.placeholder` to feed data.
Also, tensorflow v1.3 add a new method `tf.contrib.predictor` to do this. Read more in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/predictor

Answer (score 0):

can you post your result of objgraph? It will help to clarity if this is a tensorflow issue or a general python issue.